# modify titlebar color and setting icon

Tags: android, styles, titlebar

It's possible to change titelbar appearence? i would make it transparent and change default settings icon with a custom image. This is how my theme is write:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">

</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/my_bg</item>

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
    <item name="android:textColor">#colorhere</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/WindowTitleBackground</item>
</style>

<style name="WindowTitleBackground">     
    <item name="android:background">#colorhere</item>    
</style>
```

and don't forget to check

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Android Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator), it is a very useful tool for styling your Action Bar.